# Multiple instances of the class

Tags: c#

I edited my post informing more details.

I have a Terminal class and I dynamically create some instances of it.

It has a timer that if the Lista  > 0 will communicate with the device.

```
public class Terminal 
{
        public string Endereco { get; set; }
        List<string> Lista = new List<string>();
        System.Timers.Timer timer;
 
        public Terminal()
        {     
            this.timer = new System.Timers.Timer(); 
            this.timer.Interval = 500;     
            this.timer.Enabled = true;         
            this.timer.Elapsed += ProcessaTimer;
        }

        private void ProcessaTimer(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {   
              if (Lista.count > 0)      
                 ProcessaLista();
        }      

        public void ProcessaLista()
        {
            //Send command to device

        }

       public void AdicionaLista(Comando comando)
        {
            Lista.Add(comando));
        } 
}
```

I have the Principal class that instantiates the Terminal class and a method that receives information from other processes:

These instances are dynamic, I put these values ​​just to exemplify

```
public class Principal
{
    public Principal()
    {
        Terminal Obj = new Terminal();
        Obj .Endereco = "192.168.0.100";

        Obj = new Terminal();
        Obj .Endereco = "192.168.0.200";

        Obj = new Terminal();
        Obj .Endereco = "192.168.0.300";
    }
        
    void RecebeDados(Comando comando)
    {
        //if comando.Endereco == "192.168.0.100"
        //You must add to the list referring to the instance whose address is 192.168.0.100


        //if comando.Endereco == "192.168.0.200"
        //You must add to the list referring to the instance whose address is 192.168.0.200
        //

        //if comando.Endereco == "192.168.0.300"
        //You must add to the list referring to the instance whose address is 192.168.0.300
        //

    }
}
```

Command class that receives the data

```
public class Comando
{
    public string Endereco { get; set; }
    public string Mensagem { get; set; }
}
```

The question I have is on the ReceiveData method. How to put each command received in the list corresponding to the terminal? Each command goes to the terminal equivalent to the IP address.
A command must be added in only 1 list according to IP address

How to make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options here. Using a dictionary or a list and query it with Linq. Dictionary might be the best solution:

```
public class Terminal
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Terminal> _allTerminals = new Dictionary<string, Terminal>();

    public string Endereco { get; set; }
    List<string> Lista = new List<string>();

    public Terminal(string ip) 
    {
        Terminal._allTerminals.Add(ip, this);
    }

    public static Terminal GetTerminalByIp(string ip) 
    {
        return Terminal._allTerminals[ip];
    }

    ~Terminal()  // finalizer
    {
         Terminal._allTerminals.Remove(this.Endereco);
    }

    public void AdicionaLista(string comando)
    {
        Lista.Add(comando));
    }
 }
```

And you then instantiate and get the object like so:

```
Terminal obj = new Terminal("192.168.1.1");


Terminal fetchedTerminal = Terminal.GetTerminalByIp("192.168.1.1");
```

Comment: I would encapsulate the `Dictionary` in some other class something like a `TerminalCache` rather than giving the responsibility to the same `Terminal` class.

Comment: @NavjotSingh why is this the case? While I understand the part of separation, I prefer to have it in the same class to keep _allTerminals private. If we separate the classes, we would need to implement a get/set logic, which doesn't seem to be necessary.

Comment: The reason is that the `Terminal` class should not hold the state about how many terminals are created by the client. It's simply not its state. You can maintain the same encapsulation with a separate `TerminalCache` class. Simply, have the private dictionary in that class and expose the `Add` and `Remove` method from it.

Comment: Good answer. One bug and one improvement suggestion: (1) `_allTerminals` needs to be initialized. (2) Since the programmer can't control when a finalizer is called (might not be called for ages if there is no GC pressure), the Dispose pattern might be more suitable for removing terminals from thie list.

Answer (score 0):

You create a list of objects

```
var myList = new List<Terminal>();
myList.Add(new Terminal(){Endereco = "192.168.0.100"});
...
```

you can then use linq to find the correct item

```
myList.First(t => t.Endereco == myAddress).Lista.Add(myReceivedValues);
```

Note that the this example does not handle if there is no corresponding item. You could use `FirstOrDefault` and check for null to handle this. Also, a regular list is fine if there are few values. If there are a many, say thousands or more, it would be better to use a dictionary than a plain list.